# One dataset controls other in SSRS *.rdl?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I see a mystery behaviour in my *.rdl. I have 2 datasets defined.
I have 4 parameters defined,

- `StartDate,EndDate, companyid, sitecode`

For both datasets,I have defined a select query.

- DatasetA uses @Enddate

  - DatasetB not using it( it uses, startdate, companyid, sitecode)

I want to getrid of @EndDate from datasetA too. So, im using @startdate parameter to define enddate and using that in my sql query.
eg :

```
DECLARE @eDate AS date =EOMonth(@StartDate)
```

But after getting rid of this, @EndDate, my second data retrieves less data.(ie: if it should return data from september and october, now it returns only from September) 
I checked the rdl, rowgroup/column group everywhere, but there is no any filter defined like that. I see this behaviour, only if i change @EndDate parameter from 1st dataset.

eg:
DECLARE @eDate AS date =EOMonth(@StartDate)

```
Select ..
Where date>=@StartDate AND date<=@Enddate to date<=@eDate
```

Is there any place we use parameter as a filter check? If so, how can I check it, where it has been used in the *.rdl?

Comment: `EOMonth(@StartDate)` is the end of the montth that contains `@StartDate`. How could it be from the next month?

Comment: @WolfgangKais i have posted the answer. I figured out myself. Sorry, may be my quetsion was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. This is due to Lookup function I use between both datasets. So, when dataset2 is trying to retrieve the correct number of rows, dataset1 was controlling it, becuase it didnt return rows for that date.
eg: dataset1 returns September data, while dataset 2 returns September+October data.
Due to lookup function, Dataset1 controls the dataset2's October data.